# CSS/JS - Crystalize Image efect

Tags: javascript, css, web, jquery-animate, frontend

Hi i want to achieve same result like from linked gif. I can find on related blogs or some templates. Description: Its using one image as background which are transformed into triangles. Whole backgroud are moving while you moving with mouse. When you stoped that animation continue automatic.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7837zl9ZhvVV2ZneFMzYXA5Z1E
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7837zl9ZhvVbFh3RVM1RHdlNEU

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Google js effect library or sth like this or try it yourself & post code

Comment: You could use an crystalized image and then use mouseX and mousY in js and transform in CSS

Comment: I cant find any related topic. If you know how to proceed further, please sent me a link.

Comment: Basicaly i dont want use just moving picture to sides. That efect have simulation of depth and using a paralax effect. As well as picture is transformed also shapes of triangles are transformed. That effect is really rich and nice and looks more like inside a sphere then just see 2d image moving.

Comment: Most closest is this pen https://codepen.io/clarenceng/pen/sJdyr . We have the mesh now. But each corner is need to move by cursor position. Moving a image as background inside triangle it not will be that problematic. But still i am not sure if that is a right way.